# Scrollview with Viewpager

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#dddddd">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_title"
    android:textColor="#858585" /> 

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_checkout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <CirclePageIndicator android:id="@+id/indicator_checkout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    app:pageColor="#858585"
    app:fillColor="#f19201" />

    <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_below="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:text="name"
          android:textSize="16sp" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editTextName"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingRight="10dp" />
       </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

view pager uses fragments as pages (every page contains one image) heres the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff0000" >

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/img"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/img" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my main issue is that there is big space between view pager and indicator in devices like nexus 4 in nexus 7 theres is no space is there anyway to remove that space?

Answer (score 0):

Try using android:layout_marginTop to define the space you want between the viewpager and indicator

```
<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_checkout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CirclePageIndicator android:id="@+id/indicator_checkout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    app:pageColor="#858585"
    app:fillColor="#f19201" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>          <!-- 10dp spacing -->
```